# Improve code to replace values above the median by the median value itself in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, normalization, median, quantile

I'd like to replace all the values above the median value of a column by the median value of the column itself.

Here is my DataFrame:

```
m = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': xrange(5),
    'b': xrange(5, 10),
    'c': xrange(10,15)})

print m

    a   b   c
0   0   5   10
1   1   6   11
2   2   7   12
3   3   8   13
4   4   9   14
```

Here is my solution:

```
for col in m.columns:
    quart = m[col].median()
    m[col] = [val if val < quart else quart for val in m[col]]

print m

    a   b   c
0   0   5   10
1   1   6   11
2   2   7   12
3   2   7   12
4   2   7   12
```

I am not familiar with data frame so I was wondering if it is possible to do this in a more 'pandas' way or by using some fancy linear algebra.

Thank you in advance for the reply.

---

Edit answer:

Here is a quick timeit for the solutions from hurrial and chrisb respectively:

```
%timeit m.apply(lambda col: np.where(col.median() < col, col.median(), col))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.36 ms per loop

%timeit np.minimum(m, m.median())
1000 loops, best of 3: 400 µs per loop
```

The solution using np.minimum seems to be faster.

Thank you I've learnt 2 powerful things today, np.where and np.minimum !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a handful of different ways to do this.  In general, using a list comprehension is not an efficient way express a pandas operation - that particular line could be rewritten as (see the [indexing docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)).

```
m.loc[m[col] >= val, col] = quart
```

But the whole operation could be written in one line, like this (importing `numpy as np`):

```
In [211]: m = np.minimum(m, m.median())

In [212]: m
Out[212]: 
   a  b   c
0  0  5  10
1  1  6  11
2  2  7  12
3  2  7  12
4  2  7  12
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy where](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to do it for all columns in a DataFrame:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    m = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': range(5),
        'b': range(5, 10),
        'c': range(10,15)})

    print(m)
        a   b   c
    0   0   5   10
    1   1   6   11
    2   2   7   12
    3   3   8   13
    4   4   9   14

    m.apply(lambda col: np.where(col.median()>col, col.median(), col))

    print(m)

        a   b   c
    0   2   7   12
    1   2   7   12
    2   2   7   12
    3   3   8   13
    4   4   9   14
```